# javascript can't reassignment data to array in map()

Tags: javascript

```
let obj2 = {
  level2:{
    data:"data"
  }
}

let obj2Array  = [obj2,obj2,obj2];
obj2Array.map(obj=>{
  obj = obj.levle2.data
});
console.log(obj2Array)
```

what I'm expecting is ["data","data","data"].But I still got the original data.
I know I can use forEach() to achieve this, but why I can't reassignment element in map()?

Comment: there is a syntax error its `obj.level2.data` not `obj2.levle2.data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `.map()` does not mutate the original array, it returns a new one, so you should do sth like this:

```
let obj2Array = [obj2,obj2,obj2];
obj2Array = obj2Array.map(obj=>{
  obj = obj.levle2.data
});
console.log(obj2Array)
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set `obj2Array` to the value returned by `.map()`. See below:

```js
var obj2 = {
  level2:{
    data:"data"
  }
}

var obj2Array  = [obj2,obj2,obj2];

// set to returned map
obj2Array = obj2Array.map(obj=>{
  return obj2.level2.data
});

console.log(obj2Array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Map will return new array

```
const result = obj2Array.map(obj=>{
  return obj2.levle2.data
});
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

the map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.
as this says in the documentation 
you can reAssign the obj2Array when doing map

like this

```
let obj2 = {
  level2:{
    data:"data"
  }
}

let obj2Array  = [obj2,obj2,obj2];
obj2Array = obj2Array.map(obj=>{
  return obj.level2.data
});

console.log( obj2Array )
// now it is ["data","data","data"];
```

Answer (score 0):

map() returns a new array. Try this code:

```
let obj2 = {
  level2:{
    data:"data"
  }
}

let obj2Array  = [obj2,obj2,obj2];
obj2Array = obj2Array.map(obj=>
  obj.level2.data
);

console.log( obj2Array )
```

output ["data", "data", "data"]